# Virtual BoxでゲストOSのブラウザからホストOSで動くアプリにアクセスしたい

Tags: network, virtualbox

ホストOSで動かしているアプリケーションに、Virtul Boxで動かしているゲストOSのブラウザからアクセスしたいのですが、*can't reach this page*となってしまいます。

[この記事](https://gist.github.com/wakamsha/087d5f95c8dbe07b9591)を参考にしたのですが、ゲストOSのブラウザでhttp://10.0.2.2を開くと以下の画像のようになります。しかし、pingは通ります。
[image: can't reach this page]

また、仮想マシンのネットワークの設定はこのようになっています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

何が原因なのか、そもそもこの方法が間違っているのかわからない状況です。
ご見識をお持ちの方にご教授いただけたら幸いです。

以下私の動作環境です。
ホストOS: mac
ゲストOS: Windows10

Comment: ホスト側の`netstat`で`80`番ポート(※アプリケーションの待ち受けポート)の待ち受けアドレスはどうなっていますか?

Comment: ホスト側は8080で待ち受けていたので、10.0.2.2:8080で無事アクセスできました！基本的なところを見落としていました^^; ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ホスト側の80/443ポートで待ち受けているhttp/httpsサービスがないのでは？なにがしかhttp/httpsで応答するサービスがなければ、ブラウザで話しかけても答えてくれるはずもなく。。。

ホスト側のプロセス構成（たとえば、Apache http serverが動作しているとか、IISが立ち上がっているか）を示されると、話が早いです。

Comment: >ホスト側の80/443ポートで待ち受けているhttp/httpsサービスがないのでは？ おっしゃる通りでした^^; ホスト側は8080で待ち受けているのを見落としていました..! 無事アクセスできました、 ありがとうございます！